# Why deployer is rejecting my credentials?

Tags: php, deployment, rsa-key-fingerprint

I've created a new project to deploy my sources in ubuntu. My workspace, generated by a jenkins extraction is in a webserver.
I've installed deployer in this webserver to put in another server my sources validated by jenkins.

I made a "deploy" directory into the project which includes the receipe directory, the deploy.php, and the servers.yml

I've downloaded the receipe directory because i didn't understand what the receipe/common.php is about : https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/master/recipe/common.php

Here is my deploy.php :

```
<?php
require 'recipe/common.php';
serverList('config/servers.yml');
set('repository', 'git@xx.xx.xx.xx:/opt/git/intranetv2.git');
```

Here is my servers.yml :

```
production:
    host:          xx.xx.xx.xx
    user:          administrateur
    identity_file:
        public_key: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
        private_key: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
        password: "aaaaa"
    stage:         production
    deploy_path:   "/var/www/intranet"
    branch:        master
```

I don't understand why it rejects me when i do :

> dep deploy:release production

It is unable to connect with the given credentials.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your private key always is `chmod 600`

Comment: Yes it's chmod 600, but still does not work

Comment: try with full path, rather then `~/.ssh/..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it working then you do it by hands? Do you have password on keys?